# Django getting variable from URL into view

Tags: python, django

Is it possible to get a variable in a URL to pass to a view. For example. I have a location table with many locations. If I click a location it goes to a details page of that location. The location ID gets added to the URL. I then have a link to another page/view but want to reference the location id in the next view.

urls.py:

```
url(r'^locations/get/(?P<location_id>\d+)/$', 'assessments.views.location'),
url(r'^locations/get/(?P<location_id>\d+)/next_page/$', 'assessments.views.next_page'),
```

view.py:

```
def location(request, location_id=1):
    return render_to_response('dashboard/location.html', {'location': Location.objects.get(id=location_id) })

def next_page(request):
    loc = Location.objects.get(id='id of that location')
```

Comment: Which location do you need in `next_page()` - location_id or some other one?

Comment: I need the location of the location i was on before going to the next page. Not sure if that makes any sense.

Comment: `next_page` takes exactly the same `location_id` argument as the original `location` function does, so you can use it in exactly the same way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply access it in the view function with its name

```
def next_page(request,location_id):
    loc = Location.objects.get(id=location_id)
```

Answer (score 1):

OK, I'm still not sure what exactly do you mean but I think one of the following two snippets should solve your problem:

1. The URL contains location_id so just use it in `next_page()`:

   ```
   def location(request, location_id):
       return render_to_response('dashboard/location.html', {'location': Location.objects.get(id=location_id) })

   def next_page(request, location_id):
       loc = Location.objects.get(id=location_id)
   ```
2. Pass `location_id` in request.session:

   ```
   def location(request, location_id):
       request.session['selected_location'] = location_id
       return render_to_response('dashboard/location.html', {'location': Location.objects.get(id=location_id) })

   def next_page(request):
       try: 
           selected_location = request.session['selected_location']
       except KeyError:
           # Not sure if 404 is the best status code here but you get the idea
           raise Http404
       loc = Location.objects.get(id=selected_location)
   ```

Comment: Some how i convinced myself that it was so much more complicated. Thanks